# Cannot save object to dat file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a project due in CS where I'm suppose to create a GUI program that will act as an address book. The program has add,find, and delete contacts. The program is also suppose to be able to read/save the contacts. I'm having a problem reading the contacts. Here is the code for that part.

```
PhoneDirectory Contacts = new PhoneDirectory(100);
private static final String DATA_FILE = "records.dat";

private static void readRecords() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(DATA_FILE);
    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn)) {
        Contacts = in.readObject();
    }
    } 
    catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File does not exist or cannot be read.", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
  }
```

}

Here I made a object "contacts" that stores the information the user inputs. In the line with `Contacts = in.readObject();` I get an error message in the line with `Contacts = in.readObject();`. I think I get this because `Contacts` is a variable and not an object.

What am I supposed to have instead on Contacts?

Here is the rest of my code for the project.

### Main Class

```
package console;

public class Console {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PhoneBookGUI frame = new PhoneBookGUI();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### PhoneDirectory

```
package console;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PhoneDirectory {
  private PhoneRecord[] records;
  private int numRecords;

  public PhoneDirectory(int size)
  {
      this.records = new PhoneRecord[size];
      this.numRecords = 0;
  }

    public PhoneRecord[] getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public int getNumRecords() {
        return numRecords;
    }

    public void searchRecords(String inputName)
    {
        int j;
        for (j=0; j<numRecords; j++) {
            if (records[j].getName().contains(inputName)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name:" + " " +         records[j].getName() + "\nNumber:" +" " + records[j].getNumber(), inputName, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                return;
            }
       }
    }

    public void deleteRecord(String contactName)
    {
        int i;
        for (i=0; i <numRecords;i++) {
            if (records[i].getName().equals(contactName)) {
                records[i] = records[numRecords-1];
                numRecords--;
            }
        }
    }

    public void updateRecord(String contactName, String phoneNumber)
    {
        int k;
        for (k=0; k<numRecords;k++) {
            if (records[k].getName().equals(contactName)) {
            records[k].setNumber(phoneNumber);
            break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void addRecord(PhoneRecord record)
    {
        if (numRecords < records.length) {
            records [numRecords] = record;
            numRecords++;
        }

        if (numRecords > records.length) {
            PhoneRecord [] tempArray = new PhoneRecord [records.length*2];
            for (int m=0; m<records.length; m++) {
                tempArray[m] = records[m];
            }
            records = tempArray;
        }
    }
}
```

### PhoneRecord

```
    package console;

// Represents a record containing a name and a phone number
class PhoneRecord {
  private String name;
  private String number;

  // Constructor
  public PhoneRecord(String personName, String phoneNumber) {
    name = personName;                       
    number = phoneNumber;
  }

  // Returns the name stored in the record
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  // Returns the phone number stored in the record
  public String getNumber() {
      return number;
  }

  public void setNumber(String num) {
      this.number = num;
  }
}
```

Comment: Change `catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {` to `catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace();` for more information.

Comment: which class you are serializing? have you made this class serializable?

Comment: @gurvinder372
what do you mean by serializing?

Comment: check these links on Java Serialization and DeSerialization examples

http://www.careerbless.com/java/serialization/serialization.php

http://www.javabeginner.com/uncategorized/java-serialization

http://www.programdiary.in/2012/11/serialization.html

Answer (score 1):

Typically it would be necessary to cast it back to a more specific object.

```
PhoneDirectory Contacts = new PhoneDirectory(100);
private static final String DATA_FILE = "records.dat";

private static void readRecords() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(DATA_FILE);
    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn)) {
        Contacts = in.readObject();
```

Should be:

```
PhoneDirectory contacts = new PhoneDirectory(100);
private static final String DATA_FILE = "records.dat";

private static void readRecords() {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(DATA_FILE);
    try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn)) {
        contacts = (PhoneDirectory)in.readObject();  //cast the object!
```

Comment: *"that didn't work"*  As a comment, that is about as useful as a screen door on the ISS.  What output did you see?  Copy/paste it into the question as an edit.  What did you ***expect*** to see?

Comment: It says that it cannot find the symbol, the symbol being Class Contacts. I think contacts is a a variable so in.readObject() is wrong for it. I think i'm suppose to use :records: from my PhoneDirectory class. But its an private object i think so i can't access it.

Comment: See the update to answer.  Also, class names should start with an upper case letter.  In SO, they will be colored blue.  OTOH objects should start with a lower case letter (unless they are constants, like `DATA_FILE`). SO will color those black (so it is easy to distinguish from being a `Class`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the class `PhoneDirectory` and `PhoneContant` implement the `Serializable` interface, also when reading the dat file as an Object make sure to add the proper cast statement.

Comment: By `PhoneContant` DYM `PhoneRecord`?

Comment: Exactly, sorry for the mistake